# What php timezone I use for San Francisco, California, United Stated

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

What php timezone can I use for San Francisco, California US? I have spend sometime Googling it, but really can't find anything appropriate. I know it's UTC -8. But I am not sure which one to choose from the [php.net timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think `America/Los_Angeles` should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

You would use `America/Los_Angeles`

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, for locations in California use `America/Los_Angeles`.
Remember the quotes: `date.timezone ="America/Los_Angeles"`
In the USA, the time zone constants you want to use are:

- Pacific: `America/Los_Angeles`
- Central: `America/Chicago`
- Eastern: `America/New_York`
- Mountain: `America/Denver`
- Mountain no DST: `America/Phoenix`
- Hawaii: `America/Adak`
- Hawaii no DST: `Pacific/Honolulu`
- Alaska: `America/Anchorage`

More info on [time zones in the US](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa) (there are more than you might think)

Other valid PHP values for USA:

- Puerto Rico: `America/Puerto_Rico`
- Denver: `America/Detroit`
- Kentucky: `America/Kentucky/Louisville`, `America/Kentucky/Monticello`
- North Dakota: `America/North_Dakota/Beulah`, `America/North_Dakota/Center`, `America/North_Dakota/New_Salem`
- Indiana: `America/Indiana/Indianapolis`, `America/Indiana/Knox`, `America/Indiana/Marengo`, `America/Indiana/Petersburg`, `America/Indiana/Tell_City`, `America/Indiana/Vevay`, `America/Indiana/Vincennes`, `America/Indiana/Winamac`

Here are the docs for Time Zone values for the American Continent:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

The docs linking to Time Zone values for any continent, as well as ("Other") deprecated values.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

And the Time Zone doc that is often linked to in 'php.ini' files themselves:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone
This doc links to the previously listed doc, which in turn links to the first doc I referenced.